# Google BigQuery Python Client using the wrong credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-authentication, google-iam

I am getting a "Not Authorized" error when I try to query a table in BigQuery.  I've set:

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]=<path>
```

Then used

```
client = bigquery.Client()
```

When I issue the query using

```
client.query("SELECT * from `don.book3`;")
```

I get the response:

```
Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: Table <project-name>:don.book3: User does not have permission to query table <project>:don.book3
```

OK, so I checked the service email address with

```
client.get_service_account_email()
```

and found out it was transmitting the wrong address -- the one for the default Compute Engine service account, not the one for the query service account I'd set up.  OK, so it's ignoring the environment variable that I've set.  Let's try again with:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# TODO(developer): Set key_path to the path to the service account key
#                  file.
# key_path = "path/to/service_account.json"
key_path = <path>

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path
)

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=credentials.project_id)
```

Same error.  So again I try:

```
client.get_service_account_email()
```

And got back the wrong service account address.  So I thought the credentials must be wrong, and tried:

credentials.service_account_email
And got back the right address!  So bigquery Client is shrugging off all attempts to set the credentials.
The last thing I tried was to make sure that the credentials actually had the authorization to do what I want, so I set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in a shell, checked to make sure it was properly set in the environment, and then from the command line ran:

```
bq query "select * from don.book3;"
```

And it worked fine.  So all of this experimentation established:

1. The credentials were configured correctly
2. The service account did have permission to run the query
3. The bigquery Python library was using the wrong credentials.

I'm using Python 3.8 and the following libraries:

- google-auth                   1.32.0
- google-auth-oauthlib          0.4.4
- google-cloud-bigquery         2.20.0

Has anyone run into this/knows a fix?

Comment: Please clarify where you're running the code... it seems to be on Compute Engine? Please try `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path/to/key` **before** running the code

Comment: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` are **not** used by `gcloud` (`gsutil`, `bq`) and so setting the environment variable before using e.g. `bq query select` does **not** use these credentials

Comment: I'm running this on compute engine, in a Jupyter Notebook inside a container

Comment: The call to **client.get_service_account_email()** does not return the credential's service account email address. Instead, it returns the BigQuery service account email address used for KMS encryption/decryption. The email will look similar to **bq-PROJECT-NUMBER@bigquery-encryption.iam.gserviceaccount.com** This does not solve your problem but should help not go down the wrong path to debug the problem.

Comment: This code will fetch the current credential email address: **client._credentials.service_account_email**

Comment: Thanks, I can now see the email is right, but I am still seeing forbidden, and when I use the exact same credentials for the bq command-line client the query works.

Comment: Execute the command **gcloud auth activate-service-account** and verify that **bq** still works. My guess is that the **bq** CLI is not using the same credentials as your code. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account Another possibility is that **bq** is accessing one project and your code is accessing another project. Your code is using defaults for everything. Change the code to specify all parameters when creating the client. Something is different between the CLI and your code.

Comment: I executed the command, verified that bq still works, and they are using the same credentials file.  I also verified that I'm setting the project for the client, they are using the same service account, and checked the project_id and service account by hand.  This is driving me nuts...and the opacity of the client and credentials (not to mention the terse error message) isn't helping.  But, seriously, thanks for the suggestions and references.  I appreciate them, even if we haven't yet solved it.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to authenticate to the REST API?  I could try that...

Comment: My website has several articles on creating credentials for REST APIs: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/