# How can I see the service account that the python bigquery client uses?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

To create a default bigquery client I use:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
```

This uses the (default) credentials available in the environment.

But how I see then which (default) service account is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can interrogate the credentials directly (be it json keys, metadata server, etc), I have occasionally found it valuable to simply query bigquery using the [`SESSION_USER()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/security_functions#session_user) function.

Something quick like this should suffice:

```
client = bigquery.Client()
query_job = client.query("SELECT SESSION_USER() as whoami")
results = query_job.result()
for row in results:
    print("i am {}".format(row.whoami))
```

Comment: i like it, nice and simple! :)

Comment: It is worth noticing that it won't work when currently used SA is missing bigquery.jobs.create permission.

Answer (score 5):

This led me in the right direction:
[Google BigQuery Python Client using the wrong credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68685952/google-bigquery-python-client-using-the-wrong-credentials)

To see the service-account used you can do:

```py
client._credentials.service_account_email
```

However:
This statement above works when you run it on a jupyter notebook (in Vertex AI), but when you run it in a cloud function with `print(client._credentials.service_account_email)` then it just logs `'default'` to Cloud Logging. But the default service account for a Cloud Function should be: `<project_id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`.

This will also give you the wrong answer:

```py
client.get_service_account_email()
```

The call to `client.get_service_account_email()` does not return the credential's service account email address. Instead, it returns the BigQuery service account email address used for KMS encryption/decryption.

Comment: When running on a Google compute services (Compute Engine, Functions, Run, etc),, **default** means that the credentials were obtained from the metadata service. **default** is the **alias** name. The actual identity can be fetched from the **service-accounts** section. This link provides more details such as aliases, email, identity, scopes, and token: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/default-metadata-values

Comment: Was trying to query my own credentials with secret manager and the resource manager clients, for me it was `client._transport._credentials.service_account_email`

Comment: Somehow I had been unable to discover that the default service account was this: <project_id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com. Thanks for the info!!

Comment: Although I subsequently discovered that the default account (to run scheduled jobs) was, for me, 14xxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com

Answer (score 0):

Following John Hanley's comment (when running on a Compute Engine) you can query the metadata service to get the email user name:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/default-metadata-values

So you can either use linux:

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/email" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

Or python:

```py
import requests

headers = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}
response = requests.get(
    "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/email", 
    headers=headers
)
print(response.text)
```

The `default` in the url used is the alias of the actual service account used.